# Trouble with implementing local response normalization in TensorFlow

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I'm trying to implement a local response normalization layer in Tensorflow to be used in a Keras model:

Here is an image of the operation I am trying to implement:

[image: Local Response normalization]

Here is the [Paper link, please refer to section 3.3 to see the description of this layer](http://www.cs.toronto.edu/%7Efritz/absps/imagenet.pdf)

I have a working NumPy implementation, however, this implementation uses for loops and inbuilt python `min` and `max` operators to compute the summation. However, these pythonic operations will cause errors when defining a custom keras layer, so I can't use this implementation.

The issue here lies in the fact that I need to iterate over all the elements in the feature map and generate a normalized value for each of them. Additionally, the upper and lower bound on the summation change depending on which value I am currently normalizing. I can't really think of a way to handle this without nested for loops, but this will not work in a Keras custom layer as it isn't a native TensorFlow function.

Could anyone point me towards tensorflow/keras backend functions that could help me in implementing this layer?

EDIT: I know that this layer is implemented as a keras layer, but I want to build intuition about custom layers, so I want to implement this layer using tensor ops.

Comment: What about https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/local_response_normalization?

Comment: @xdurch0 I know that exists, but I wanted to build intuition in creating custom layers in tensorflow/keras by implementing this one.